# Thread safe C# not working

Tags: c#, multithreading

when I run the following code that runs fine, but not as expected, it is assumed to run on a secure thread, but all components are frozen until it finishes running the thread, it is not supposed to run on a new thread so you can use other controls?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

   public class MyFormControl : Form
   {
      public delegate void AddListItem();
      public AddListItem myDelegate;
      private Button myButton;
      private Thread myThread;
      private ListBox myListBox;
      public MyFormControl()
      {
         myButton = new Button();
         myListBox = new ListBox();
         myButton.Location = new Point(72, 160);
         myButton.Size = new Size(152, 32);
         myButton.TabIndex = 1;
         myButton.Text = "Add items in list box";
         myButton.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
         myListBox.Location = new Point(48, 32);
         myListBox.Name = "myListBox";
         myListBox.Size = new Size(200, 95);
         myListBox.TabIndex = 2;
         ClientSize = new Size(292, 273);
         Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {myListBox,myButton});
         Text = " 'Control_Invoke' example";
         myDelegate = new AddListItem(AddListItemMethod);
      }
      static void Main()
      {
         MyFormControl myForm = new MyFormControl();
         myForm.ShowDialog();
      }
      public void AddListItemMethod()
      {
         String myItem;
         for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
         {
            myItem = "MyListItem" + i.ToString();
            myListBox.Items.Add(myItem);
            myListBox.Update();
            Thread.Sleep(300);
         }
      }
      private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunction));
         myThread.Start();
      }
      private void ThreadFunction()
      {
         MyThreadClass myThreadClassObject  = new MyThreadClass(this);
         myThreadClassObject.Run();
      }
   }

// The following code assumes a 'ListBox' and a 'Button' control are added to a form, 
// containing a delegate which encapsulates a method that adds items to the listbox.

   public class MyThreadClass
   {
      MyFormControl myFormControl1;
      public MyThreadClass(MyFormControl myForm)
      {
         myFormControl1 = myForm;
      }

      public void Run()
      {
         // Execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns
         // 'myFormControl1' control's underlying window handle.
         myFormControl1.Invoke(myFormControl1.myDelegate);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Looks like most of the code is in the delegate that you invoke on the UI thread.  You should only invoke when you need to update a control not for something that's going to do a loop with a sleep in it.  You could avoid the extra thread if you made this `async` and used `Task.Delay` instead.

Comment: Your own comment says it all: "Execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns 'myFormControl1' control's underlying window handle." That thread is the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

> it is assumed to run on a secure thread, but all components are frozen
>   until it finishes running the thread

When you are invoking some delegate on control, the delegate will run on UI thread. I.e. this code will run on UI thread:

```
  public void AddListItemMethod()
  {
     String myItem;
     for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
     {
        myItem = "MyListItem" + i.ToString();
        myListBox.Items.Add(myItem);
        myListBox.Update();
        Thread.Sleep(300); // freeze UI thread
     }
  }
```

> it is not supposed to run on a new thread so you can use other
>   controls?

You cannot use controls from non-UI threads.

Purpose of using background threads is a long-running operations which are not related to UI. E.g. you can read some file from disk, query api, or you can run some long-running calculation (n-th fibonacci number). If you'll run these kind of things on UI thread, then your application will freeze. So you should run such operations on non-UI thread and return to UI *after* you have finished long-running operation (though you can notify user about progress of long-running operation).

If you want to periodically do something with UI then consider using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` component. Set timer interval to 300 and add Tick event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myListBox.Items.Add($"MyListItem{myListBox.Items.Count + 1}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Invoke` runs the delegate on the UI thread, so you're just creating a thread that just tells the UI thread to do all the work.  Instead you can use `async` and `await` along with `Task.Delay` to simplify your code.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String myItem;
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        myItem = "MyListItem" + i.ToString();
        myListBox.Items.Add(myItem);
        myListBox.Update();
        await Task.Delay(300);
    }
}
```

That will run the code on the UI, but now the `await Task.Delay(300)` will not block the UI thread allowing it to handle other UI events and stopping the freezing problem.

Comment: Thank you it works just fine!,  I don't know how but it supposed that work like a thread? Can I instantiate another class when a click the button for doing some stuff in background and i still working with the main UI without problem?, if so it is fantastic!

Comment: Basically this code is compiled into an asyncronous state machine.  It breaks up the running of the code at each `await` and during the 300 milliseconds the UI thread is free to do other stuff.

Comment: I understand, so if the line  {myListBox.Items.Add(myItem);} take about a 1 minute to finish the UI it will be freeze any way?

Comment: If i need to have windows reading a log file and updating a textbox, all the ui will be freezed until the log stop.

Comment: You can use `async` methods to read from a file (most .Net streams have async versions of the regular synchronous methods).  In fact IO is one of the main reasons to use `async`